# How do I take node and node's subnodes from XML file?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I want to take subnodes from an XML file, but with main node, so each product has two subnode.

I can write to file --> "product name", "info" but I need to write;

--> Test1, test1 info, variation1 barcode

--> Test1, test1 info, variation2 barcode

--> Test2, test2 info, variation1 barcode

--> Test2, test2 info, variation2 barcode

How can I do this? Please help me.

My XML file:

```
-<Product>    
    -<ProductName>
              test1
    </ProductName>    
    -<Shortinfo>
         asd
    </Shortinfo>       
    -<info>
       asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
    </info>

  -<ProductOption>        
      -<Option>    
       <variationID>1</variationID>    
       <Barcode>71079901877542</Barcode>        
      </Option>    

       -<Option>    
        <variationID>2</variationID>    
        <Barcode>71079901877542</Barcode>        
       </Option>    
  -</ProductOption>
-</Product>


-<Product>    
    -<ProductName>
              test2
    </ProductName>    
    -<Shortinfo>
         asd
    </Shortinfo>  
    -<info>
       asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
    </info>   

  -<ProductOption>        
      -<Option>    
       <variationID>1</variationID>    
       <Barcode>71079901877542</Barcode>        
      </Option>  

       -<Option>    
        <variationID>2</variationID>    
        <Barcode>71079901877542</Barcode>        
       </Option>    
  -</ProductOption>
-</Product>
```

C#

```
 private static string EditText(XDocument xDocument) 
 {
    var stbu = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var result in xDocument.Descendants("Product").Select(x => new
    {
        title = (string)x.Element("productName"),
        shortinfo = (string)x.Element("shortinfo"),
        info = (string)x.Element("info"),
        barkod=(string)x.Element("ProductOption").Element("Option").Element("Barcode")
    }))
    {
        stbu.AppendLine($"{result.barcode},{result.title},{result.shortinfo},{result.info}");
    };

    return stbu.ToString();
}
```

'option' subnode s 'product' and 'barcode' subnode s 'option'

Comment: There is one XML Reader and one XML Writer class. Are they not avalible for you or do they have some issues?

Comment: I can get main nodes, but i cant subnode. i cant reach to "variation" tag. variation tag is subnode's subnode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML Linq.  Look at my code below where I used Descendants.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement product in doc.Descendants("Product"))
            {
                string productName = (string)product.Element("ProductName");
                string info = (string)product.Element("info");

                foreach (XElement option in product.Descendants("Option"))
                {
                    string variation = (string)option.Element("variationID");
                    string barcode = (string)option.Element("Barcode");

                    Console.WriteLine("Product Name : '{0}', Info : '{1}', variation : '{2}', barcode : '{3}'",
                        productName.Trim(), info.Trim(), variation.Trim(), barcode.Trim());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that's the right way, it was very helpful. thanks :)